# How do I make a header stay under a centered picture in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my first time asking of Stack Overflow so I'm sorry if the formatting isn't perfect. Anyways, I'm working on a website which uses Bootstrap 3. It has an image that is centered in the middle of the page vertically and horizontally. It also has a background image. I am trying to put a header under the image in the center but the header goes to the top of the page. There is a fixed nav-bar on the bottom of the page.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>
            App
        </title>
        <style>
            html {
                background-image: url("gradiant.png");
            }
            .logo {
                position: absolute;
   top: 40%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   margin-top: -216.5px; 
   margin-left: -236.25px; 
            }
            .nav-pills li a {
                color: white;
                font-size: 250%;
            }
                .nav-pills li a {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all .5s;
border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.nav-pills li a:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ffffff;

}
.dropdown{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ffffff;

}
.nav-pills > li > .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .dropdown-toggle {
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }
.dropdown-toggle:active, .open .dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: white !important;
    border-color: #ffffff !important;
    }
.nav-pills {
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-pills > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
}
h1 {
     position: absolute;
     color: #ffffff;
}
  </style>
    </head>
    <body>
 <img alt="App" src="app.png" width=472.5 height=433 class="logo" align="middle" >
 <h1>App</h1>
 <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-fixed-bottom">

          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

   <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Apps <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="app.html">App</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

    </ul>
  </li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using an image for a gradient instead of just doing a linear gradient with CSS? Check out this question if you're unfamiliar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046721/how-to-use-bootstrap-3-gradient-for-background-in-css

Comment: I use an image because my logo uses the same gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Bootstrap-specific answer, but what you can do is create a container for the logo and apply the CSS, you're currently applying to the image, to the container. Then just put the heading below the image in the container:

```css
html {
    background-image: url("gradiant.png");
}
.logo-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -216.5px;
    margin-left: -236.25px;
}
  .logo-container img {
    width:100%;
  }
.nav-pills li a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 250%;
}
.nav-pills li a {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all .5s;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.nav-pills li a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
.dropdown {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
.nav-pills > li > .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
.dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
.dropdown-toggle:active,
.open .dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: white !important;
    border-color: #ffffff !important;
}
.nav-pills {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-pills > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
h1 {
     position: absolute;
     color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="logo-container">
  <img alt="App" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" class="logo" align="middle" >
  <h2>Title goes here</h2>
</div>
<h1>App</h1>
<ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-fixed-bottom">
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Apps <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="app.html">App</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```